# InnoDB: Any way to kill an update and prevent rollback?

Tags: mysql, innodb, kill

In case I ran a very long update (which has millions of records to update and is going to take several hours), I was wondering if there is anyway to kill the update **without** having InnoDB rollback the changes.

I would like the records that were already updated to stay as they are (and the table locks released ASAP), meaning to continue the update later when I have time for it.

This is similar to what MyISAM would do when killing an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a single `UPDATE` statement, I may be wrong but I doubt that's possible. However, you can always split your query into smaller sets. Rather than:

```
UPDATE foo SET bar=gee
```

... use:

```
UPDATE foo SET bar=gee WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 100;
UPDATE foo SET bar=gee WHERE id BETWEEN 101 AND 200;
UPDATE foo SET bar=gee WHERE id BETWEEN 201 AND 300;
...
```

This can be automated in a number of ways.

Comment: Thanks, and this is exactly what I will do next time. For now, this does not help since the query is already running.

Comment: I like this concept. BTW - in my case not all records in the table will be updated, so using `id BETWEEN X AND Y` will modify a different amount of records, many times zero records. I think using `LIMIT 100` can finish in significantly less iterations, actually modifying a 100 records each time, until no records are updated. This may have worse performance though - I will test both.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a black_hole table, with fields to match your needs for the update statement.

```
CREATE TABLE bh_table1 
 ..field defs
) ENGINE = BLACKHOLE;
```

Now create a trigger on the blackhole table.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ai_bh_table1_each AFTER INSERT ON bh_table1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  //implicit start transaction happens here.
  UPDATE table1 t1 SET t1.field1 = NEW.field1 WHERE t1.id = NEW.id; 
  //implicit commit happens here.
END $$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

You can do the update statement as an insert into the blackhole.

```
INSERT INTO bh_table1 (id, field1) 
  SELECT id, field1 
  FROM same_table_with_lots_of_rows
  WHERE filter_that_still_leaves_lots_of_rows;
```

This will still be a lot slower than your initial update.
Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: Every statement is run in a transaction. Autocommit means that the transaction is commited after each statement. But update statement, that updates milions of rows, is still 1 statement, hence one transaction. Autocommit off means that the first query starts transaction, but the transaction is not completed unless explicit call to commit is made.

Comment: AFAIK Darhazer's comment is correct. My update is running in a transaction no matter what. Killing it using 'kill XXX' will roll it back anyway. I was wondering if there is any other kill syntax which can prevent this.